# How to retrieve repetitive data in sql without using loops?

Tags: sql-server

I have a help-desk system in which there is a table with ticket details. I have a table in SQL server with data something like this,

```
ID    status        create_date       closing_date       
---------------------------------------------------------
 1    closed    2015-01-01 14:06:30   2015-01-02 18:06:42
 2    closed    2015-01-01 15:16:42   2015-01-02 08:12:10
 -      -               -                     -
 -      -               -                     -
```

Now I want to display the number of hours taken to close the tickets in past 5 weeks looking at last 2 months.

For ex., I want to show data for past 5 weeks from today (49,50,51,52,1) and each week should look at the last 2 months closed tickets. (for week 49, the data should be between week 49 - 60 days and week 49 end date).

Currently, I have used loop to get the result like this,

```
declare @week_start datetime, @week_end datetime, @week int, @last_week int, @week_number int
set @last_week = datepart(wk, dateadd(wk, -1, getdate()))
set @week_number = dbo.F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR(dateadd(wk, -5, getdate()))
set @week = @last_week - 4
set @week_start = dateadd(day, -60, dateadd(wk, -5, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 4)))
set  @week_end = dateadd(wk, -5, DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate())/7, 4))
while  @week <= @last_week
begin
select @week_number as week_number,
cast(avg(cast(Datediff(hour,create_date,closing_date) as decimal (10,2))) as decimal(10,2)) Hours
FROM tickets
where closing_date between @week_start
and @week_end
--group by dbo.F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR(closing_date )
set @week_start = dateadd(wk, 1, @week_start)
set @week_end = dateadd(wk, 1, @week_end)
set @week = @week + 1
set @week_number = @week_number + 1
end
```

which returns the following data,

```
week_number    Hours
--------------------
   49         121.56
   50         129.06
   51         125.57
   52         125.90 
   53         130.52
```

Now, I do not want to use the loop because it messes up the week numbers and I also want to display ISO week numbers.

So here is my modified code,

```
select dbo.F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR(closing_date) as week_number,
cast(avg(cast(Datediff(hour,create_date,closing_date) as decimal (10,2))) as decimal(10,2)) Hours
FROM tickets
where closing_datebetween DATEADD(wk, -5, getdate()) and DATEADD(wk, -1, getdate())
group by dbo.F_ISO_WEEK_OF_YEAR(closing_date)
```

But it returns the following data which is incorrect as it's not looking at the past 2 months from a particular week,

```
week_number    Hours
--------------------
   49         142.69
   50         262.76
   51         95.50
   52         85.39 
   1         75.90
```

I do not know how can I modify my query to get the same result without using loops.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to gain full context without seeing what your underlying data it, but my first guess would be that in your iterative code, you have a sliding window (i.e. 5 weeks ago you're looking at past 2 months + 5 week, 4 weeks ago, past 2 month  +4 , etc). Your select statement is statically looking at the values as of one point in time.

If you're running SQL Server 2012+ you can use row frames to define such a sliding windows (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx). Alternatively, and I say this with caution, if you only need to return 5 rows, hitting the same table 5 times for a report like this isn't that bad. If you can provide sample data, you may be able to get some more code-specific replies.